# Graphics card DirectX backwards compatability?

Tags: graphics-card

If a graphics card lists its DirectX API as `DirectX 10.1`, is that card backwards compatible with older systems that run Winows XP which only supports up to DirectX 9? Or does the system need to support the *GPU's* DirectX API version or higher? Or in other words, do you have to be running Windows Vista or 7 to install a DirectX 10.1 graphics card.

Thanks!

Comment: That not the graphics card's DirectX API, that's the card's driver's DirectX API. (Which means, obviously, that the card *can* support that API but not that it *must*.)

Comment: *> That not the graphics card's DirectX API, that's the card's driver's DirectX API.*   @DavidSchwartz, that's not entirely true. Many cards are listed as DX8, DX9, DX10, etc. indicating the DX version upto which the card support. Updating the driver cannot make a DX9 card magically support DX10 functions, anymore than updating the drivers of a PS2.0b card could not make it support PS3.0 (which is why many people were upset when games started coming out that *required* PS3, thus forcing people to upgrade their perfectly good cards).

Comment: @Synetech: Nothing you are saying conflicts with anything I'm saying. The driver will select a DirectX API version to present based on whatever factors it is coded to take into account which typically includes both its own limitations and the card's limitations.

Comment: *> which typically includes ... the card's limitations.*   Yes, so the *card* does indeed have a specified DX version that is supported. So when you complained that it is not the card's DX API, you were just quibbling about semantics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the manufacturers website has the drivers for Windows XP, then it will work on Windows XP.  However, it will only function up to the DirectX 9 capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

DirectX 9 applications will run on higher runtimes(e.g. directx 11) but this does not mean that drivers will be universally available for older OS-es.

I think that directly addresses your question.

Comment: `DirectX 9 applications will run on higher runtimes(e.g. directx 11)`   Not always, there are plenty of games that use DX9 and will not run on Windows 7; they will throw an error about needing DX9 and prompt you to install it. `:-/`